# Calling an Update function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function to update the password of an user. Here is my function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_user(userid int, upassword text) RETURNS integer AS  $$
    BEGIN
 UPDATE tbl_user 
     SET password= upassword 
 WHERE user_id = userid;
 SELECT 1;
 END;
 $$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I tried to execute this functions using.

```
SELECT update_user(1, 'test');
```

I got an error as

```
ERROR:  control reached end of function without RETURN CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function
```

I'm not sure where I go wrong. Please help me on this. I'm new to creating functions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say the function `RETURNS integer`, but you don't tell it what to return. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks, I have added "SELECT 1;" before "END;", the functions got execution and the password has been updated. Can you help me to capture the affected rows so that i would pass it a return value for validation.

Comment: It's in the manual - see `GET DIAGNOSTICS`. But I really don't understand why you're wrapping the statement in a function like this, rather than just doing that directly in the call site.

Answer (score 3):

Every PL/pgSQL function needs a `RETURN` statement. But in your case you can do with a SQL language function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_user(userid int, upassword text) RETURNS void AS $$
  UPDATE tbl_user 
    SET password = upassword 
    WHERE user_id = userid;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Only when you need to do more elaborate processing (for instance, using local variables, processing logic, or a trigger) do you need a PL/pgSQL function.

Comment: Or just redefine your function as `RETURNS VOID`.